# Parsing a JSON file with GSON in Java without model

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse a JSON file with GSON with the following structure:

```
[
   {
      "datasetid":"geonames-postal-code@public-us",
      "recordid":"2d026c84998f913f0f0f5dd9f0d17ab0f78f5c44",
      "fields":{
         "longitude":"18.3475",
         "coordinates":[
            54.1486,
            18.3475
         ],
         "admin_name1":"Pomerania",
         "admin_name2":"Gda\u0144sk County",
         "admin_name3":"Przywidz",
         "postal_code":"83-041",
         "admin_code3":"220405",
         "country_code":"PL",
         "admin_code1":"82",
         "latitude":"54.1486",
         "admin_code2":"2204",
         "place_name":"Sucha Huta",
         "accuracy":"6"
      }
   },
   {
      "datasetid":"geonames-postal-code@public-us",
      "recordid":"c5f689d377a9a460d3b06b772fc621088484e719",
      "fields":{
         "longitude":"18.505",
         "coordinates":[
            54.2232,
            18.505
         ],
         "admin_name1":"Pomerania",
         "admin_name2":"Gda\u0144sk County",
         "admin_name3":"Pruszcz Gda\u0144ski",
         "postal_code":"83-041",
         "admin_code3":"220404",
         "country_code":"PL",
         "admin_code1":"82",
         "latitude":"54.2232",
         "admin_code2":"2204",
         "place_name":"\u017bu\u0142awka",
         "accuracy":"6"
      }
   }
]
```

I only need to read the values in "fields". I have looked all over the internet and all I can see are examples that operate in classes / models.

How can I read without class and model?

```
BufferedReader br = null;
Gson gson = new Gson();
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\res\\postal_codes.json"));
```

Comment: It's nothing wrong creating models with one field even if the JSON to deserialize have more fields. If you want "very generic" solution, read it as `JsonElement` (see the `Streams` class in Gson). The former takes less memory footprint and is more type safe.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use **Gson's default parsing function [`Gson#fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html).**

I have included a few values that you can print as an example.

```java
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\res\\postal_codes.json"));
JsonArray jsonElements = new Gson().fromJson(reader, JsonArray.class);
for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonElements) {
    JsonObject item = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    // Write datasetid.
    String datasetid = item.get("datasetid")
            .getAsString();
    System.out.println("Dataset ID: " + datasetid);
    // Write recordid.
    String recordid = item.get("recordid").getAsString();
    System.out.println("Record ID: " + recordid);
    // Write country_code.
    JsonObject fields = item.getAsJsonObject("fields");
    System.out.println("Country Code: " + fields.get("country_code").getAsString());
    // Write coordinates.
    JsonArray coordinates = fields.getAsJsonArray("coordinates");
    System.out.println("Coordinates: " + coordinates.toString());
}
```

**Note:** The best method is to work with POJO's. I recommend that you care about it, but for some reason it works if you want to continue without it.